# Oracle12c LRM 00190 error on win10

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Installed oracle12c. 
"sqlplus /as  sysdba" gives "connected to idle instance" msg.
But when I try to log on to a user I get "LRM 00109 error".

"Sqlplus" gives "oracle not available" error msg.
"Tnsping orcl" outputs "cannot resolve parameter" error.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Start up the database?

Comment: @Littlefoot  startup : LRM 00109 cannot open file initorcl.ora"

Comment: Have you ever been able to connect to that database? If so, what changed since? Because, the parameter file seems to be missing, so you'd have to create it (Google for how to do it).

Comment: @Littlefoot Connecting for the first time.. Will do the same.. thanks

Comment: OK; though, when you were installing the software, did you also create a database? I'm not familiar with 12c setup, but I know that previous installations did install a database you could have used instantly. As if your setup didn't go well ...